# Stuck on a error in my CLI (undefined method `title' for []:Array (NoMethodError))

Tags: ruby

Let me preface this by saying I'm really new to Ruby. I'm trying to create a CLI and here's what I got for it so far:

```
class Topspotifysongs::CLI

def start
  Topspotifysongs::Scraper.new
  get_song
end
def get_song
  input=gets.strip.to_i
  song = Topspotifysongs::Songs.get_song_details(input)
  puts "........................................................................"
  show_song_details(song)
  puts "........................................................................"
  puts "Would you like to show another song? (y/n)"
  repeat_or_done
end

def show_song_details(song)
    Topspotifysongs::Songs.get_song_details(song)
    puts "----------- #{song.title} by #{song.artist} -----------"
    puts ""
    puts "Ranking:           #{song.rank}"
    puts ""
    puts "Streams:           #{song.streams}"
    puts ""
    puts "Link to song:      #{song.spotify_url}"
    puts ""
    puts "---------------------------------------------------------------------"
end
```

and here is my songs file:

```
class Topspotifysongs::Songs

  attr_accessor :title, :artist, :rank, :streams, :spotify_url

  @@all = []

  def initialize(title=nil, artist=nil, rank=nil, streams=nil, spotify_url=nil)
    @title = title
    @artist = artist
    @rank = rank
    @streams = streams
    @spotify_url = spotify_url
    @@all << self
  end
  
  def self.all
    @@all
  end

  def self.get_song_details(song)
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://spotifycharts.com/regional"))
    doc.css("idk").collect do |x|
      title = x.css("td.chart-table-track.strong").text
      artist = x.css("td.chart-table-track.span").text
      rank = x.css("td.chart-table-position").text
      streams = x.css("td.chart-table-streams").text
      spotify_url = x.css("td.a.href").value
    end
  end
end
```

I'm sure theres other errors I need to knock out, but I've been stuck on this error for hours and my brain is starting to fry:

````
/home/z****/****/topspotifysongs/lib/topspotifysongs/cli.rb:25:in `show_song_details': undefined method `title' for []:Array (NoMethodError)```
````

Comment: I know this is a dumb question... but how is it an empty array? Shouldn't it get the info from self.get_song_details?

Comment: Sorry. It’s not an empty array. It’s just an array. You can’t call `title` on an array. It’s like trying to call `[‘hello’, ‘world’].title`. The reason you’re getting an array back is because you’re using `.collect` in your `get_song_details` method.

Comment: Should I use ```each``` instead? I get an undefined method error when I do that. Thank you by the way

Comment: `each` returns `self`. You can use an array, but you’ll have to know where in the array the title is. What does your array look like?

Comment: I was assuming self.get_song_details was my array, but I guess not